# How can I figure out the font used by a class file

Tags: fonts, document-classes

I have a document class that isn't as thoroughly documented as I might like, and I'd like to figure out what font it uses. Is there an easy, universal way to get TeX to tell you directly what font is being defined by the class file? Preferably in a way that will show me how I can define the font in my own file, in TeX code?

I have read this question that asks how to [find fonts in pdfs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture). This doesn't tell me what the font is called in TeX, and is very round-about. Preferably, I'd like to know the *name of the font **package*** that I want to use.

Comment: If you produce some pdf with that class you can check the pdf properties to see the used fonts.

Comment: If you're referring to the font that is used to generate some output (PDF), then you can following the guidelines in [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919/5764) (possible duplicate).

Comment: That does look like a duplicate - didn't find it in my search though.

Comment: @Werner I know this is five years old now, but this question did get distinct answers from the one's in the document/picture one. I think that I really did have a distinct question here - I have the TeX file of the document, and I want to figure out how TeX is defining the font.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The document

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\expandafter\show\the\font

\stop
```

puts the following information on the terminal and log

> \OT1/cmr/m/n/10=select font cmr10.

showing that `article` is using the font `cmr10` known to latex as

```
\fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{cmr}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont
```

Just replace `article` by any class you wish to test.

Comment: It helps to precede this statement with [`\wlog{ ... }`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69478/write-to-logfile) so you can find it more easily in the log.

Comment: @StevenJeuris I was assuming running in interactive mode where `\show` stops and shows the tex as if for an error message