# Are there any guides to using LaTeX's log files and other output?

Tags: output

I am using WinEdt and MikTex.

When I PDFtex my document, it produces a rather huge log file, most of which is stuff I don't need, but some of which is important.

Are there any good guides to using this file (and the other output LaTeX produces) to help edit a  document?

Comment: Use the search function of your editor and search for "warning". That will take you to many of the important parts…

Comment: winedt has a rather good interface to wander through the important messages. ctrl+E will open a window and there you can jump to the next error/warning.

Comment: Each package (and the document itself) can write to the log, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69478/write-to-logfile. It is up to the package authors to determine which information is added to the log, so it can be anything - there are no restrictions or explicit guidelines as far as I know. Of course most packages try to include only useful diagnostics, but there can be a lot of it. As a general strategy it is mostly useful to look at the end of the file, if there is a problem it is usually diagnosed there.