# Nested loops to process groups of pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, loops

The following MWE processes groups of pictures, placing them on a slide with a caption below the picture. The slides are made using the `pdfscreen` package, and the picture and caption placement is done by creating a `tikz` node.

Lists of pictures and their captions are created with, for example: `\newcommand*{SetA}{pic1/caption 1,pic2/caption 2}`. The sets of pictures are in `\newcommand*{\MySets}{SetA,SetB}`.

I use a `foreach` loop to process each set of pictures. My question is: How can I wrap a `foreach` loop around the inner loop to process all the picture sets?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[nopanel,screen]{pdfscreen}
\margins{1cm}{1cm}{1cm}{1cm}
\screensize{15.875cm}{20.32cm}

\newcommand*{\SetA}{example-image-a/caption A1,example-image-a/caption A2}
\newcommand*{\SetB}{example-image-b/caption B1,example-image-b/caption B2}
\newcommand*{\MySets}{\SetA,\SetB}

\begin{document}
%\foreach \Set in {\MySets}{
\foreach \myphoto/\mycaption in \SetA {% How to change \SetA to \Set to process all the pictures in each set
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth,height=0.9\textheight]{\myphoto}};
\node[below=3mm] (b) at (a.south) {\mycaption};
\end{tikzpicture}
\clearpage
}
%}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this particular application, where the outer `\foreach` uses a list of lists, you can expand the macro containing the inner list before starting the inner loop.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[nopanel,screen]{pdfscreen}
\margins{1cm}{1cm}{1cm}{1cm}
\screensize{15.875cm}{20.32cm}

\newcommand*{\SetA}{example-image-a/caption A1,example-image-a/caption A2}
\newcommand*{\SetB}{example-image-b/caption B1,example-image-b/caption B2}
\newcommand*{\MySets}{\SetA,\SetB}

\newcommand{\eforeach}[2]{\expandafter\doeforeach\expandafter{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\doeforeach}[2]{\foreach #2 in #1}

\begin{document}

\centering
\foreach \Set in \MySets {
  \eforeach{\Set}{\myphoto/\mycaption} {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (a) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth,height=0.9\textheight]{\myphoto}};
    \node[below=3mm] (b) at (a.south) {\mycaption};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \clearpage
  }
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are consistent in naming your sets, you can loop over the characters (in this case `A` and `B`) and build a macro with `\csname` and `\endcsname`. MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[nopanel,screen]{pdfscreen}
\margins{1cm}{1cm}{1cm}{1cm}
\screensize{15.875cm}{20.32cm}

\newcommand*{\SetA}{example-image-a/caption A1,example-image-a/caption A2}
\newcommand*{\SetB}{example-image-b/caption B1,example-image-b/caption B2}
\newcommand*{\MySets}{\SetA,\SetB}

\begin{document}
  \foreach \id in {A,B}{
    \edef\Set{\csname Set\id\endcsname}
    \foreach \myphoto/\mycaption in \Set {
      \centering
      \begin{tikzpicture}
          \node (a) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth,height=0.9\textheight]{\myphoto}};
        \node[below=3mm] (b) at (a.south) {\mycaption};
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \clearpage
    }
  }
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a two things here:

Firstly, you need to omit the braces around `\MySets` in the outer `\foreach`.

Secondly, `\foreach` is written in such a way that the inner loop is the equivalent of

```
\foreach \myphoto/\mycaption in {\SetA} {
```

when you try to loop the way you want to. In your case we can remedy this by expanding everything before the first `\foreach`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[nopanel,screen]{pdfscreen}
\margins{1cm}{1cm}{1cm}{1cm}
\screensize{15.875cm}{20.32cm}

\newcommand*{\SetA}{example-image-a/caption A1,example-image-a/caption A2}
\newcommand*{\SetB}{example-image-b/caption B1,example-image-b/caption B2}
\edef\MySets{{\SetA},{\SetB}}

\begin{document}

\foreach \Set in \MySets {
    \foreach \myphoto/\mycaption in \Set {
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node (a) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth,height=0.9\textheight]{\myphoto}};
            \node [below=3mm] (b) at (a.south) {\mycaption};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \clearpage
    }
}

\end{document}
```

If your use case is not more complex than this, you could also just avoid the nested macro definition in the first place:

```
\newcommand*\MySets{%
    {   example-image-a/caption A1,
        example-image-a/caption A2},
    {   example-image-b/caption B1,
        example-image-b/caption B2}%
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Half for fun, here is a solution using LaTeX3. It takes care of expanding your `\SetA`, `\SetB` and `\MySets` macros:

- early enough to make the `\foreach` happy, and;
- exactly once, so that in case your inner lists (`\SetA` and `\SetB`) contain things that should not be expanded, or should not be expanded too early, this solution could be usable as is (as opposed to solutions that use `\edef\MySets{{\SetA},{\SetB}}` or something similar, which fully expands `\SetA` and `\SetB`).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[nopanel,screen]{pdfscreen}
\margins{1cm}{1cm}{1cm}{1cm}
\screensize{15.875cm}{20.32cm}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \SetA
\clist_new:N \SetB
\clist_new:N \MySets

\clist_gset:Nn \SetA {example-image-a/caption~A1, example-image-a/caption~A2}
\clist_gset:Nn \SetB {example-image-b/caption~B1, example-image-b/caption~B2}
\clist_gset:Nn \MySets {\SetA, \SetB}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \ross_iterate_on_sets:NN #1#2
  {
    \clist_map_variable:NNn #2 #1
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \RossIterateOnSets { m m }
  {
    \ross_iterate_on_sets:NN #1 #2
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \ross_iterate_on_pics:nn #1#2
  {
     \foreach #1 ~in~ {#2}
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \ross_iterate_on_pics:nn { nV }

\NewDocumentCommand \RossIterateOnPics { m m }
  {
    % First expansion of #2 (e.g. \Set -> \SetA or \SetB)
    \exp_args:Nno
    % Second expansion: use the *value* of \SetA or \SetB for the second
    % argument of \ross_iterate_on_pics:nn
    \ross_iterate_on_pics:nV {#1} {#2}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\RossIterateOnSets{\Set}{\MySets} {%
  \RossIterateOnPics{\myphoto/\mycaption}{\Set} {%
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node (a) at (0,0) {%
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth,height=0.9\textheight]{\myphoto}};
      \node[below=3mm] (b) at (a.south) {\mycaption};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \clearpage
  }%
}
\end{document}
```

If one of the elements of a comma-list should contain a comma, just wrap the whole element in braces.

In order to see for yourself that things are expanded as advertised before being fed to `\foreach` (i.e., each of `\SetA`, `\SetB` and `\MySets` is expanded exactly once before arriving in the hands of `\foreach`), please consider this slightly modified version, where we print to the terminal and log file precisely what the inner loop does:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand*{\dontExpandMe}{If this gets printed, it is GAME OVER.}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \SetA
\clist_new:N \SetB
\clist_new:N \MySets

\clist_gset:Nn \SetA {example-image-a/caption~\dontExpandMe A1,
                      example-image-a/caption~A2}
\clist_gset:Nn \SetB {example-image-b/caption~B1,
                      example-image-b/caption~\dontExpandMe B2}
\clist_gset:Nn \MySets {\SetA, \SetB}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \ross_iterate_on_sets:NN #1#2
  {
    \clist_map_variable:NNn #2 #1
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \RossIterateOnSets { m m }
  {
    \ross_iterate_on_sets:NN #1 #2
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \ross_iterate_on_pics:nn #1#2
  {
     \typeout { \string\foreach \unexpanded {#1} ~in~ \unexpanded {{#2}} }
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \ross_iterate_on_pics:nn { nV }

\NewDocumentCommand \RossIterateOnPics { m m }
  {
    % First expansion of #2 (e.g. \Set -> \SetA or \SetB)
    \exp_args:Nno
    % Second expansion: use the *value* of \SetA or \SetB for the second
    % argument of \ross_iterate_on_pics:nn
    \ross_iterate_on_pics:nV {#1} {#2}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\RossIterateOnSets{\Set}{\MySets} {%
  \RossIterateOnPics{\myphoto/\mycaption}{\Set}
}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output (on the terminal and in the log file) of the two `\typeout` commands of this example:

```
\foreach\myphoto /\mycaption  in {example-image-a/caption \dontExpandMe A1,example-image-a/caption A2}
\foreach\myphoto /\mycaption  in {example-image-b/caption B1,example-image-b/caption \dontExpandMe B2}
```

As you can see, the `\dontExpandMe` macro is not expanded. In the full example, this means it would not be expanded before the `\foreach` is executed.

Note: `\mycaption` is followed by two spaces in this output:

- the first one is from `\typeout` printing a control word (i.e., a control sequence composed of letters only);
- the second one is because we put an explicit space token (`~` in `expl3` syntax) before the word `in`.

Similarly, `\dontExpandMe` is followed by exactly one space in the output because it is a control word printed by `\typeout`.

Note 2: using `\unexpanded` is necessary to see the tokens as is. This is because `\typeout` expands everything inside its argument (like `\message`, but `\typeout` is also `\protect`-aware as explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69480/73317)).

Comment: I added explanations and a modified example to illustrate how expansion of the `clist` variables is done in my solution (one of its strong points).

Answer (score 2):

A `listofitems` approach.  Note that, since a comma is used to separate elements of the individual sets, the caption may need to be embraced, lest any commas appearing in the caption mess with the parsing.  Alternatively, a different parsing separator could be used.

Note also with `listofitems` parsing, there is no computational need to have regularity in the set names.  For example, one could have `\newcommand*{\MySets}{\Foo,\Bar}`, and as long as the sets `\Foo` and `\Bar` were defined appropriately, the parsing would work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[nopanel,screen]{pdfscreen}
\margins{1cm}{1cm}{1cm}{1cm}
\screensize{15.875cm}{20.32cm}
\newcommand*{\SetA}{example-image-a/caption A1,example-image-a/caption A2}
\newcommand*{\SetB}{example-image-b/caption B1,example-image-b/caption B2}
\newcommand*{\MySets}{\SetA,\SetB}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\begin{document}
\setsepchar{,}%
\readlist*\SetList{\MySets}%
\foreachitem\z\in\SetList[]{%
  \setsepchar[!]{,!/caption}%
  \expandafter\readlist\expandafter\ThisSet\expandafter{\z}%
  \foreachitem\zz\in\ThisSet[]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (a) at (0,0) {\includegraphics%
    [width=0.9\linewidth,height=0.9\textheight]{\ThisSet[\zzcnt,1]}};
    \node[below=3mm] (b) at (a.south) {\ThisSet[\zzcnt,2]};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \clearpage
  }
}
\end{document}
```