# Print file in log

Tags: logging, message

I have a file and I'd like to print it in the log file. The problem is that if I add a new line with `^^J`, often two newlines are added when the size of the line to print is exactly the maximum width of the line in the console (which occurs… always since I print the log of a latex file 90% of the times).

MWE:
`demo.txt`

```
(/nix/store/6z1x24dwqp88qh769isg4y769w47d1x2-texlive-combined-2022/share/texmf/
tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/nix/store/6z1x24dwqp88qh769isg4y769w47d1x2-texlive-combined-2022/share/texmf/
tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))

! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
```

foo.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Look at the log.

\ExplSyntaxOn
\ior_new:N \g__my_read_ior

\cs_new:Nn \robExt_write_file_in_log:n {
  \ior_open:Nn \g__my_read_ior {#1}%
  \ior_str_map_inline:Nn \g__my_read_ior {%
    \message{\tl_to_str:n{##1}^^J}%
  }%
}
\message{--------------}
\robExt_write_file_in_log:n {demo.txt}
\message{--------------}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: Worth noting that `\tl_to_str:n` is useless here. ■ tl;dr I don't think it's possible. That having said why don't you use `\immediate\write18` / `\typeout`?

Comment: Maybe [compiling - Write to logfile - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69478/write-to-logfile/69480#69480) .

Comment: @user202729 thanks, good point. I just became aware of `\typeout`, and to be honest the differences with message are still a bit unclear to me ^^ It deals differently with newlines mostly? Another related stuff: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/705502/message-add-symbol-in-front-of-new-lines-even-if-there-is-a-line-break/705523#705523