# \message: add symbol in front of new lines even if there is a line break

Tags: logging

If I do:

```
\message{^^J! my very long message that will be cut on many lines because LaTeX for some weird reasons like to manually cut the lines instead of letting the terminal do it^^J}
```

I will see something like this in the log:

```
! my very long message that will be cut on many lines because LaTeX for some we
ird reasons like to manually cut the lines instead of letting the terminal do i
t
```

But I'd like to prepend `!`  to all the lines, because TeXstudio will only print lines starting with a `!` as errors. How could I automatically add a symbol when a new line is created in the log?

MWE

```
\documentclass[]{article}


\begin{document}

\message{! my very long message that will be cut on many lines because LaTeX for some weird reasons like to manually cut the lines instead of letting the terminal do it}


\end{document}
```

EDIT: to clarify, I'd like the log to contain:

```
! my very long message that will be cut on many lines because LaTeX for some we
! ird reasons like to manually cut the lines instead of letting the terminal do
! it
```

(or even better if it could break at word boundaries, but hey, lets not ask too much)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes What would that change?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes yes, but I want `!` to be on every line cf my edit). I'm thinking I could manually write my own `\message{}` that cuts the string in chunks, but there might be better solutions.

Comment: Does your edit indicate you would like to add arbitrary line breaks in the middle of a `\message`?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes no, just I'd like to add a symbol `!` in front of any line in the log

Comment: `\message` is a tex primitive you can not control its line breaking other than setting the line length to be very long so no line breaking occurs.

Comment: you can of course break up the string by hand, but why use `\message` in that case rather than `\write` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yeah, I’m currently doing the code to break the string by hand, seems to work ok. What do you mean with write? The goal is to write in the log file.

Comment: yes the usual way is to use `\write-1{kkkk}` or similar (`\message` is a little weird as it doesn't force a linebreak per message), latex's `\typeout` for example is `\write` not `\message`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, I introduce `\xmessage`, which takes an extended message and breaks it at the first space that exceeds a set limit (here 4o characters).  Each new line begins with a `!` character.

Note that any given command sequence in the `\xmessage` only counts as a single character.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newcounter{charcount}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\xmessage[1]{\bgroup%
  \aftertokcycle{\typeout{! \the\cytoks}}%
  \tokcycle{\addcytoks{##1}\stepcounter{charcount}}
  {\processtoks{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}\stepcounter{charcount}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}\stepcounter{charcount}\splitline}{#1}%
  \egroup}
\newcommand\splitline{%
  \ifnum\value{charcount}>40\typeout{! \the\cytoks}%
  \setcounter{charcount}{0}\cytoks{}\fi}
\begin{document}
\xmessage{my very long message that will be cut on many lines because LaTeX for some weird reasons like to manually cut the lines instead of letting the terminal do it}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Split the input (possibly after full expansion, with the `*`-variant) at spaces and then prepare the message computing the total length of the line and taking the decision to break if the `max_print_line` limit is exceeded.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% get the current length of error lines
\sys_get_shell:nnN { kpsewhich ~ -var-value=error_line } {} \l_tmpa_tl
\int_const:Nn \c__tobiasbora_prefixmessage_limit_int { \l_tmpa_tl }

\NewDocumentCommand{\prefixmessage}{sO{!}m}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
   {
    \tobiasbora_prefixmessage:ne { #2 } { #3 }
   }
   {
    \tobiasbora_prefixmessage:nn { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__tobiasbora_prefixmessage_text_seq
\str_new:N \l__tobiasbora_prefixmessage_text_str
\int_new:N \l__tobiasbora_prefixmessage_len_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \tobiasbora_prefixmessage:nn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nne \l__tobiasbora_prefixmessage_text_seq { ~ } { \tl_to_str:n { #2 } }
  % start up
  \str_set:Nn \l__tobiasbora_prefixmessage_text_str { #1 }
  \int_zero:N \l__tobiasbora_prefixmessage_len_int
  % prepare the string to output
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__tobiasbora_prefixmessage_text_seq
   {
    \int_add:Nn \l__tobiasbora_prefixmessage_len_int { \str_count:n { ##1 } + 1 }
    \int_compare:nNnTF
     { \l__tobiasbora_prefixmessage_len_int }
     >
     { \c__tobiasbora_prefixmessage_limit_int - \str_count:n { #1 } }
     {
      \str_put_right:Nn \l__tobiasbora_prefixmessage_text_str { ^^J #1 ~ ##1 }
      \int_set:Nn \l__tobiasbora_prefixmessage_len_int { \str_count:n { ##1 } + 1 }
     }
     {
      \str_put_right:Nn \l__tobiasbora_prefixmessage_text_str { ~ ##1 }
     }
   }
  % output
  \iow_term:e { ^^J \l__tobiasbora_prefixmessage_text_str ^^J }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tobiasbora_prefixmessage:nn { ne }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\prefixmessage{my very long message that will be cut on many 
  lines because \LaTeX for some weird reasons like to manually
  cut the lines instead of letting the terminal do it}

\def\foo{(something in the middle)}

\prefixmessage*[>>>]{my very long message that will be cut on many 
  lines because LaTeX \foo\space for some weird reasons like to manually
  cut the lines instead of letting the terminal do it}

\stop
```

Output on the terminal and in the log file

```
! my very long message that will be cut on many lines because \LaTeX for some
! weird reasons like to manually cut the lines instead of letting the terminal
! do it


>>> my very long message that will be cut on many lines because LaTeX
>>> (something in the middle) for some weird reasons like to manually cut the
>>> lines instead of letting the terminal do it
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version with LaTeX3: lines are separated by `\robExtPrefixLogMessage` (if you use it in your code, choose other names not to collude with my CTAN library), and will prefix it with `\robExtPrefixLogMessage`.

```
\def\robExtMessageWithPrefixNumberLines{^^J}%
\cs_new:Nn \robExt__message_with_prefix:n {
  \str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str {#1}  
  \int_compare:nNnTF {\str_count:N \l_tmpa_str + \str_count:N \robExtPrefixLogMessage} > {78} {
    \typeout{\robExtPrefixLogMessage \str_range:Nnn \l_tmpa_str {1} {78 - \str_count:N \robExtPrefixLogMessage}\robExtMessageWithPrefixNumberLines}
    \robExt__message_with_prefix:x {\str_range:Nnn \l_tmpa_str {78 - \str_count:N \robExtPrefixLogMessage + 1} {-1}}
  }{
    \typeout{\robExtPrefixLogMessage \l_tmpa_str \robExtMessageWithPrefixNumberLines}
  }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \robExt__message_with_prefix:n { x }
```